# How to add icon end with no-warp text with the primeng table cell

Tags: angular, primeng

i want to add font-awesome icon end with text that text can no-warp

The text...[ICON]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sqjt.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer, and working fine

```
**.ui-table .ui-table-thead>tr>th, .ui-table .ui-table-tbody>tr>td, .ui-table .ui-table-tfoot>tr>td {
max-width: 100px !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
white-space: nowrap !important;
```

}**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<td class="nowrap">
  <span>This is the long text This is the long text</span>
  <span><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></span>
</td>

.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i applied but text is nowrap but icon not showing